# Python pandas read_excel method KeyError 'show'

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read an excel File, extension .xlsx, with Pandas and it is displaying a `KeyError: 'show'`

This is the full error stack trace:

```
File "~/Python_VirtualEnv/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 653, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
File "~/Python_VirtualEnv/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 424, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
File "~/Python_VirtualEnv/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 138, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "~/Python_VirtualEnv/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 812, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
File "~/Python_VirtualEnv/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 271, in process_stream
    meth(self, elem)
File "~/Python_VirtualEnv/api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 397, in do_sheet
    bk._sheet_visibility.append(visibility_map[state])
KeyError: 'show'
```

If I open and re-save the file, then it reads perfectly fine so I am thinking the problem is with some formatting or Excel versioning that pandas is unable to read.

In my app, I can't ask the user to re-save so it needs to work right away. I have tested ~1000 files and there is only one that is giving this error.

What can I do to make sure the file is read when this error is thrown?

Comment: can you link the version of xlrd that is used here? I looked through the code and it seems what you have installed is not what is the current version.

Comment: It's 1.2 so the latest version

Comment: Just have seen that the package is not maintained anymore. I truly do not understand why pandas relies on it. xlrd completely ignores how releases work, they  merged bug fixes into the master without making a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error you are having is happening because of an old error from xlrd.

The problem has been fixed in the [Pull Request #323](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/commit/6ec98fc74796a6439c6dd64ed71597a3c50d4986#diff-74efe2926535c21edf8087564ce132fe)

Update the pandas package, the xlrd package and it should work again.

Comment: Damn thanks man. That's definitely the problem. Now I have another weird problem. If I manually change the code in the Pull Request, it is all good but if I reinstall via pip again, it still installs the xlrd package without that bug fix. I don't want to try a manual install or update of xlrd as my production environment is dependent on pip. Any clean suggestions?

Comment: `pip install git+https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd.git` should do the trick. This downloads the package directly from the github master branch of xlrd and hopefully replaces the xlrd packages that comes as a dependency from pandas.

Comment: I love you. Thanks so much